# Identifying cluster centroids using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, clustering, centroids

I have a data set of points which are grouped into clusters like so:

[image]

I'd like to use ArcGIS or Python to create a point layer of the centroids of each cluster but I can't seem to find the right tools. I looked into hot spot analysis but it doesn't seem to apply, since my features aren't numerically weighted. I also tried the Integrate tool with a reasonable tolerance but I didn't see any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To aggregate the clusters use [grouping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Grouping_Analysis/005p00000051000000/) which produces a field SS_GROUP then for each unique SS_GROUP in the feature class [create a convex hull](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003q000000) then use [Feature to Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000) to obtain the centroid of that particular cluster, with polygons you can specify *inside* to guarantee that banana shaped polygons produce a centriod that is inside the polygon but that wont matter too much as the convex hull cannot be banana shaped - that would be concave.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - can I use Feature to Point with points as an input? I don't have polygons at the moment (those red circles are just for illustration).

Comment: Oh, I thought they were real. You want to cluster them and then get the centroid of that.

Comment: See edit. After grouping you may want to dissolve by SS_GROUP to a multipoint so it's one feature per group. I think that you can still create a convex hull over 1 multipoint feature. This would make iteration easier.

Comment: The [Mean Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p00000018000000) tool might also be useful here? I haven't used it but it looks like it's built for this purpose

Comment: Hey @StephenLead, you'd think that would be good but it creates a *single point* at the centre of all the points, not the clusters. Sometimes useful, but usually not.

Comment: I figured you could use Mean Center in conjunction with your SS_GROUP idea, using the case field to separate them into clusters (this may not give any advantages over the Feature to Point tool though)

Comment: That would work just as well. The internal maths is probably very similar. If you made a layer each time with a definition query there's no need for bunches of temp datasets... I like it!

Comment: This seems like a great solution - the only problem is I'm using 9.3 so I don't have all the right tools. I'm going to look into getting a copy of 10 and try this out. Another thought - will the convex hull tool have a problem if a group has less than 3 points?

Comment: Yes and no, the convex hull of 2 points is a line and the convex hull of 1 point is a point but apart from that it's fine. If you don't (and can't) get ArcMap 10.x then your only choice is to research the algorithms and duplicate them in ArcPy.. Not something I'd like to do personally.

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS has a few tools in the [**Spatial Statistics toolbox**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p00000002000000) that might be useful.

**[Mean Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Mean_Center/005p00000018000000/)**

> Identifies the geographic center (or the center of concentration) for
>   a set of features.

**[Median Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Median_Center/005p00000019000000/)**

> Identifies the location that minimizes overall Euclidean distance to
>   the features in a dataset.

**[Central Feature](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Central_Feature/005p00000015000000/)**

> Identifies the most centrally located feature in a point, line, or
>   polygon feature class.

I think the Mean Center would be most useful here when used with the Case Field option.

Comment: I see now that previous comments describe what I just posted at approximately the same time.

Comment: The median / mean centre still needs the *case field* or it will create only one point.

Comment: Yes, that's true, and I mention that at the end of my answer.