# Determining centroid of clusters of points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clustering

I've basically got the same issue as [Identifying cluster centroids using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101598), but can't find a way to transplant the ArcGIS solution to QGIS.

I have household-level geo data for 10 villages spread out across the country. I need to find the central point of these household clusters, so that I can create a 10km buffer around that central point.

I am new to QGIS.

[image]

Comment: In GRASS GIS 7, there is an addon for this: v.centerpoint which calculates center points for point clouds, lines and areas (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/v.centerpoint.html). Not sure how to use GRASS Addons from QGIS, though.

Comment: Oh dear. So there's a GRASS GIS plugin for my QGIS. Just poked around it, but didn't get very far. So there's no way to do this within QGIS drop-down menus?

Comment: Maybe the QGIS developers can enable installations of GRASS Addons?

Comment: Can use one of the QGIS geoalgorithms or generate convex hulls from the points and take the centroids of the hulls. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192973/how-to-get-mean-coordinates-of-features-from-a-point-layer

Answer (score 5):

If it does not need to be QGIS you can do the task rather simply with OpenJUMP. In the beginning you have a road and a cluster of villages.

[image]

Select the villages and merge them to one multipoint feature. Tool opens with mouse right click.
[image]

Keep the new multipoint feature selected and find Geometry Functions toolbox from menu Tools-Analysis. Select the Centroid of A function, run it for selected features only and ask OpenJUMP to create a new layer for the result.

[image]

You can save the computed centroid of your cluster into shapefile if you want to continue with other tools than OpenJUMP. Or perhaps you want to continue and use the buffer tool first from Tools-Analysis-Buffer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use Processing toolbox > Vector Analysis > Mean coordinate(s)

It returns a point layer with the center of mass of geometries in an input layer.