# Getting the mean coordinates of point features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, centroids, mean

I have a vector layer containing several points and I would like to generate the mean coordinates of these points, using QGIS only if possible. I'm looking for something similar to centroids, but for points. Any hint?

Comment: Please edit the question to define "centroid" in this context... Is it the center of the bounding rectangle?  The center of mass?  The visual center of the convex hull?  The X/Y of the point closest to one of  those (and therefore "inside" the shape)?

Comment: I would combine all the points into one MultiPoint and take the centroid of that. Works with OpenJUMP, not yet tried with QGIS.

Comment: Are you wanting to do something similar like this? [Clusters of points: Determining the centroid (QGIS)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112842/clusters-of-points-determining-the-centroid-qgis)

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to comments asking clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to scan comments for critical information.

Comment: @Vince: Yeah I'm going to edit it, but I asked the question an hour ago and I'm just checking for answers now. Easy, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I saw another response as being from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centroid property is only for polygon layers.
If you have a point layer you can calculate the "Mean Coordinates" from Qgis geoalgorithms.

Answer (score 4):

`Vector > Analysis Tools > Mean coordinate(s)` yields the average coordinates aka their centroid of any vector layer.

Answer (score 1):

If your points have a common attribute you can run "Vector  >  Geoprocessing Tools  >  Convex Hull(s)..."

```
Input Vector = points
Create convex hulls based on input field = check, use the field with the
                                           common attribute
```

This will create a polygon for each group of points.  Now you can create your generalised points "Vector  >  Geometry Tools  >  Polygon Centroids..."

Convex hull creates a minimum area polygon around the points. The centroid of which will then be the generalized centroid for each point cluster.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, *Mean coordinate(s)* is the tool in QGIS you want, which functions to get the centre of gravity of the points

To help visualise what this tool does, below is the use of *Mean coordinate(s)* on a dense point layer with the `Unique ID field` set to a locality attribute, as well as *Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation)* on the same layer

*Mean coordinate(s)* functions somewhat like it is grabbing the centre of gravity of a heatmap of the points

[image]